# Swift - Delayed animation after ReloadData

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, tableview, reloaddata

currently I am working on a project with a search bar over a map, like Google Maps. Currently I am trying to get a code of block to be delayed for a second after tableView.reloadData() has executed, however I can't figure it out.

My TableViews and everything run fine. I've looked all over SO but haven't found a solution that works.

To visualize what I'm trying to achieve, I'd like to have the UI work like the Google Maps search bar, when you type in something, hit search, it will collapse on itself (which works fine in my project), and after some loading/delay another TableView slides up. I'm trying to achieve the later where there's a delay in my search bar's function, then the TableView of results slides up.

I can't figure out the delayed part, because when I throw in my animation code after tableView.reloadData(), the original position of the TableView gets shifted and messed up.

Anyone have any ideas how to go about this? Thanks.

```
var mapSearchResults: [MKMapItem]? {
    didSet {
        print(mapSearchResults)
        tableView.reloadData()


    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi again Kamran. Initially, I tried to write a code block where the TableView would animate to a certain position after reloadData(), to do this I tried a few things including... [1] tableView.beginUpdates() / endUpdates() [2] UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false) [3] contentOffset ---- all of which didn't produce the effect I wanted---- So I took a look at GoogleMaps to try and mimic their UI where the TableView animates after a delay when you tap the Search Button, I've been doing Google searches but haven't found any information that can help me.

Comment: Nevermind Kamran, I've solved it! Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Sherman How did you solve it? You could use Grand Central Dispatch to delay a block of code (using `async after` method).

Comment: @Chris yep! I did exactly that... the exact line of code I used... `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1))`